# Why is this array of type Any?

Tags: julia, type-inference

Why is Q of type Any?  I am trying to multiply it against a Float64 array and getting "no matching method"

```
qi=5000.0
b=0.9
di=0.6
mnths=600.0
t=1.0

AI=(1/b)*((1-di)^-b-1)
ai=AI/12

q(t)=qi/(1+b*ai*t)^(1/b)
Q=[q(t-1) for t=1:mnths]
```

Answer (score 5):

Type inference in the global scope is harder (since global variables can be reassigned anywhere). So either do

```
Q=Float64[q(t-1) for t=1:mnths]
```

or wrap everything in a function (which could be a good idea anyway).

Comment: or declare the constants as such using `const`.